# android onitemclick() not working....

Tags: android, listview, onitemclick

I am new to android programming so pls go easy with me...

I have created an app which has a listview that contains name it fetches from the "name" field in my database hosted locally using XAMPP.

When user clicks on a name in listview, it should fetch the "fileName" field from database that contains the webserver URL associated with each name.

Currently when click on a listview item, it streams the audio BUT:

- It doesnt open mediaplayer or streaming player on the emulator
- If track 1 is playing and I click on track 3 it plays both tracks simulateously
- as there is no media/stream player view you cannot pause/stop/play the track that is being played

Here is my code

```
      private void connect() {

      List<String> r = new ArrayList<String>();

      ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,r);

      final ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

      try {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet("myServer/android/files.php");  
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
            data=EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            Log.e("STRING", data);


      try {                            
           JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(data);
           JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("mp3s");

           for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
            ID = jsonChildNode.getInt("ID");
            name = jsonChildNode.getString("Name");
            FileName  = Uri.parse(jsonChildNode.getString("FileName"));                           
            Log.e("STRING", name);
            //r.add(ID);
            r.add(name);


            list.setAdapter(adapter);   


            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

                    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

                    try{
                    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), FileName);
                    mp.prepare();
                    mp.start();                 
                    }
                    catch(IOException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }

                }
            });



           }


      } catch (JSONException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
      }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.d("HTTPCLIENT", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("HTTPCLIENT", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }                
    }
```

Its the code in my onItemClick() that is faulty:

```
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

                    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

                    try{
                    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), FileName);
                    mp.prepare();
                    mp.start();                 
                    }
                    catch(IOException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }

                }
            });
```

Please can you correct me and help me so that:

- the streaming player opens and plays the listview item when I click on it
- it only plays 1 track at a time and if user starts another track it stops existing track

Thanks for any responses I may receive

Comment: semi answer : If track 1 is playing and I click on track 3 it plays both tracks simulateously - your creating new MediaPlayer everytime create the Mediaplayer as a Global variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code to Open Default Media Player for Mp3 :

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/file.mp3");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivty(intent);
```

as for your second question : your creating new MediaPlayer everytime create the Mediaplayer as a Global variable

Comment: Thanks for your reply...does your code go into the on item click()??? But how will my program know to play the item that has been clicked?? Pls clarify thanks

Comment: since your getting the Filename according to the selection and its Mp3 pass it to the Uri.parse and it will open the file with the Default mediaPlayer .. now about MediaPlayer its only backcode for playing files if you want to build the UI depends how you want to go.

Comment: on a real device it will open the default player or let the user select from a list of players installed on the device

Comment: thank you very much. I am testing on my device. It asks user to select from browsers to play file in because of the URI I am passing in from my code. I need it do as you say "let the user select from a list of players on device" pls help me acheive this....thank you so much

Comment: `code`      String extension = MimeTypeMap
                .getFileExtensionFromUrl(file);
        String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
                .getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
        Intent mediaIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        mediaIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(file),
                mimeType);
        startActivity(mediaIntent); `code` - changed my code to this and it works fine :-) thanks for your help anyways

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the list data to adapter after adding values to list `r` not in start add this line

```
ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,r); after r.add
```

Comment: What's the difference in the way I do it at the moment??